# $xu_x + yu_y + (u_x)^2 + (u_y)^2 - u = 0$ represents

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

A solution of the PDE

$xu_x + yu_y + (u_x)^2 + (u_y)^2 - u = 0$ represents

1) an ellipse in the x - y plane

2) a parabola in the u - x plane

Can anyone please help me out? I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: With "represents an ellipse in the $x-y$ plane" I guess they mean that $u$ is on the form $u = ax^2 + by^2$ (with $a,b>0$) (?) If so then to check [1] you just need to substitute this form into the equation and try to solve for $a,b$. With "a parabola in the $u-x$ plane" I guess they mean that $u$ is on the form $u = cx^2$.